# How to add more columns in pentaho reporting?

Tags: pentaho

I can use method to create ‘50’ number of column report in Pentaho Reports.

When i drag and drop the columns when i have seen only 5 0r 6 columns..
Can any one tell me how to add more no of columns in Pentaho Reporting?

Answer (score 0):

Make the page wider, or your columns thinner. The page can be virtually any width, so you can go as wide as you want, e.g. if exporting to Excel and so on.

There is certainly no limit I've hit on number of columns anyway.  But do consider if this is an end user report it still probably has to be printable in some way!

Comment: Hi Codek,I Tried but its not working...plz tell me any other way?